# what page to show if something goes wrong in business logic

Tags: web-applications

If something goes wrong with my server, I show '404 error page'. What should I show if something goes wrong in business logic that is vital to content of the requested page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's something the user can fix by for instance changing a value in some form, have an error message directing your user how to perform the fix.

If something goes terrible wrong in the business logic itself, like some webservice call fails. You shouldn't return a 404, which means 'Resource not found', but instead return a 500, which says 'Internal server error'. Create a page that tells the user something went wrong, and what they might do (retry, contact you, something else..). Don't forget to log and send an e-mail to the developers/administrators when something like this occurs, so they can take action.

Comment: Currently, when something goes wrong my framework - kohana - displays the error and call stack on a page. I assume that I have to intercept this view and replace it with custom error page, correct? The error and callstack will be logged.

Comment: Yes that is correct. You'll want to make sure the error and call stack itself aren't shown. There are a ton of guides on how to achieve a custom error page with kohana.

Answer (score 2):

If the error is related to a specific attribute, I suggest to display an error message next to your form input.

Again, if the error is simple or a result of a web form, the error messages should be redirected back to the form to be displayed.

If the error is more generic or too complex, your should have an error page to report on error details.

Comment: Also, when possible, your form should report validation errors on the client side before the user submits the data. This is a convenience for the user and will reduce invalid data sent to the server by accident. (It doesn't stop malicious users, though, so it should still be revalidated server side.)